# passing a function to a widget and call function when button press in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing an issue in flutter where I want to pass a function to a button widget and when the button is pressed, I want that function to be called. however, the opposite is occurring. When I passed the function to the widget, the function gets called and when I press the button, nothing happens. The function doesn't get called.

Here is the button widget code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:finsec/core/res/export_resources.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:reactive_dropdown_search/reactive_dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';

import '../../../income/data/models/AddEditIncomeModel.dart';
import '../../data/repositories/app_database.dart';

class SaveButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  SaveButtons({
    Key key,
    this.onPressCallback
  }) : super(key: key);


  final VoidCallback onPressCallback;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SaveButtonsState();
  }
}

class SaveButtonsState extends State<SaveButtons> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: button(save, database),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: margin_10dp),
        Expanded(
            child: button(save_and_continue, database),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget button (String saveType, AppDatabase database) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: colorPrimary,
        onPrimary: white,
        shadowColor: Colors.grey,
        elevation: margin_3dp,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(margin_5dp)),
        minimumSize: Size(margin_100dp, margin_40dp), //////// HERE
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        onPressCallback;
      },
      child: Text(saveType,   style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: text_size_16, color: white)),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is partial code on how I am passing the printLine function to my widget SaveButtons

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(incomeTitle), backgroundColor: colorPrimary,),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endTop,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
        onPressed: () async {    }
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.save,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        child: ReactiveForm(
          formGroup: viewModel.form,
          child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin_20dp),
              child: Column(
                children: [
              
                  SaveButtons(onPressCallback: printLine())
                ],
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
    );

  printLine() {print('TEST FUNCTION CALLBACK');}
```

when SaveButtons is called, the text TEST FUNCTION CALLBACK is printed. I don't want the `printLine` function to be executed when SaveButtons is called.  I want printLine to execute when the button is pressed in the `SaveButtons` widget. Currently, when I pressed the button the `printLine` function doesn't get called. it only gets called when passed as a parameter to SaveButtons and SaveButtons widget is called from the main class. can someone help me fix this so that the correct action is performed? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
  final VoidCallback onPressCallback;
```

with:

```
  final void Function() onPressCallback;
```

and change this:

```
  SaveButtons(onPressCallback: printLine())
```

with this:

```
  SaveButtons(onPressCallback: printLine)
```

and change:

```
  onPressed: () {
    onPressCallback;
  },
```

with:

```
onPressed: () {
        onPressCallback();
      },
```

Comment: thank you Gwhyy. this works perfectly. I have a quick question.  you said to use SaveButtons(onPressCallback: printLine) instead of SaveButtons(onPressCallback: printLine()).  what if i want to pass a parameter to printLine.   lets say printLine definition is as follow:  printLine(String i) {print('TEST FUNCTION CALLBACK' + i);}   how can i call the function with parameters?

Comment: the don't pass the function directly to the peoperty, do something like this:   SaveButtons(onPressCallback: () { printLine(); /*here your other methods*/})

Comment: passing   methods like this SaveButtons(onPressCallback: printLine()) is considered that you're passing a function call which will execute it automatically without clicking actually on the button

Comment: however, passing it like this SaveButtons(onPressCallback: () { printLine(); /*here your other methods*/} will pass the method which when the button is clicked it will execute printLine() method

Comment: Choosing this as the right answer since it helper you could help the next person getting in this trouble.